# How to parse SOAP response in ColdFusion

Tags: xml, soap, coldfusion

[image: My Data]

Put very simply, how do I go about retrieving the data?  I want an array that I can loop over to display this data.  This is what I've been trying, without success:

```
<cfset apicall = XMLParse(httpResponse.filecontent)>
<cfset certArray = xmlSearch(apiCall,"//BNEHFTPOfficerRosterSvcResponse/BNEHFTPOfficerRosterSvcResult/BNEHFTPOfficerRosterSvcResponse")>
```

That second line in particular, or any variation thereof, returns an empty array.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

[image: Next...]

After modifying my code per the suggestion:

```
<cfset cols = xmlSearch(apiCall,"//*[local-name()='BNEHFTPOfficerRosterSvcResponse']")[1].XmlChildren>
```

If I dump that, I get the second image.

Now I'm trying to get closer to having the array of data I need.  I've tried adding another .XmlChildren to it but that throws an error.  This is confusing! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your XPath seaerch above is based from the root of the XML object, which is currently `soap:Envelope`, you need to either recurse in to your XML object to the `soap:Body` before running your XPath query

`var soapBody = apiCall[ "soap:Envelope" ][ "soap:Body" ];`

Then you can perform you Xpath search above.

Alternately you can use a more open XPath search string, which will perform the recursion for you:

```
xmlSearch(apicall,"//*[local-name()='BNEHFTPOfficerRosterSvcResponse']")
```

Comment: Thank you!  That got me closer.  I just updated the post with another image of my results and code change.